# I want to run the high side switch without using the bootstrap

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I'm making a circuit for study purposes.

I want to deliver gate signal without using bootstrap method, overall circuit configuration is as follows.[image]

The problem is operating the secondary high side switch. My switch needs a floating power supply of 10V to receive a gate signal of 10V.

So, here's the diagram you thought of.
[image]

Based on the diagram, the circuit diagram is as follows.
[image]

Please check if there is anything wrong with the diagram and circuit diagram, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common solution for half-bridges that can't use a normal bootstrap circuit (i.e. ones that need to reach 100% duty cycle). It'll work perfectly fine.

You can save a few components (and some money) by using 12V or 15V for the high-side supply directly. Gate drivers don't need a very precise supply voltage. Isolated 12V and 15V DC/DC modules are quite inexpensive. (One part that should work is the CUI PDSE1-S12-S12-S.)

Similarly, you can also use 12V for the low-side driver supply. That way, you need only one buck converter to go from your 20..30 Volt input rail to 12V, which you can then use to power both the isolated DC/DC converter and the low-side driver. That's just two converters in total to power everything.

Comment: Thank you. I will revise it to reflect your opinion